# How to Parse String (Large string Object) Object to json?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am able to Parse this line using Gson:

`realm_access: {roles: [offline_access,uma_authorization] } }`

But, am not able to parse this line using Gson:

`realm_access: {roles: [offline access,uma authorization] } }`

Just as the later String has space in between it throws the following error

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 533 path
>   $.resource_access     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
>     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)     at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774)

Comment: It is a Json you can not make something like `offline access` with spaces, expect if you are using quotation like `"offline access"`.

Answer (score 0):

In Json you can not make something like `offline access` with spaces, expect if you are using double quotation like `"offline access"`.

In Json format, Usually, developers use underscore `_` like `offline_access` or camel case like `offlineAccess`.

So, if you want the value with spaces, just add it between double quotation.

Comment: Here using double quotes " does not work as it was throwing compile time error , but worked with single quotes ' 

Thanks for your help

Comment: Me too, when using Typescript Angular, I use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not important to conserve the spaces, you can remove them using a regex:

```
String json = realm_access: {roles: [offline_access,uma_authorization] } };
json.replaceAll("\\s+","");
String output = new Gson().toJson(json);
```